# Can I get some recommendations for an Open Source Trouble Ticket system?

Tags: open-source-gis

When I research trouble ticket systems a lot of them are for programming.  I am interested in something more general purpose.  Some things that would be a bonus would be:

-Integrated with Drupal
-PostgreSQL based
-web interface for Clients

Opinions and advise is needed.

Comment: wilsongis, I think this question will be more appropriate for the serverfault.com site: since this answer doesn't depend on anything GIS related, we don't have any insights over the larger general IT community (e.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=issue-tracking&sort=votes)

Comment: ... or even StackOverflow.  Even though that community is mostly programmers, you'd almost certainly find excellent advice there.  Just specify your needs clearly.

Comment: I realize it is a general question but I like hearing wheat the GIS community uses.

Comment: I think if the question has something in it that makes our answers as GIS users superior, then it'd be a great question. But if it's just asking us about our more general experiences as IT users, then this isn't a good place to get an excellent response, because we're a small userbase relative to programmers or IT folks.

Comment: I agree that it can be useful to know what colleagues and peers are using even when the question itself is not GIS specific. It could be important, for example, for interoperability. As currently phrased however this question does not draw out that kind of connection and relevancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure about the question, but I assume TRAC would be perfect for you. You can easily tailor it to your needs.

Check [pgrouting](http://pgrouting.postlbs.org/) for a simple TRAC GIS implementation.

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)
[DrupalTrac Plugin](https://apollo.openband.net/trac/drupal-modules/wiki/TracPlugins)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Trac, and [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is a pretty good choice too. Redmine is really nice in that it's a better general project management tool (not just for software projects), and integrates very well with multiple VCSses.

If you're doing open source and don't want to host it yourself, [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/) and [code.google](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/) have issue tracking built in too.